# Writing wifi device driver for smartphones

Tags: android, iphone, linux, wifi, android-wifi

1. Do I need to write a separate d.d for every smartphone working on Android?
2. Do I need to write a separate d.d for iPhone 4s and iPhone 4?

Comment: Why would you need to write *any* device drivers? Are you planning on creating a new wifi device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shouldn't think so - they are all pretty standard - just do some QA on 3 different handsets. I know for a fact that Samsung has a unique driver for bluetooth, but I have not seen a difference on any device's wifi.

[Samsung Galaxy bluetooth drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596978/samsung-galaxy-bluetooth-drivers)

Are your devices not connecting to your computer? You should only have to write the driver if your device has wifi, but cannot connect to your computer, in which case you should search for them online first.

Comment: I need to write the d.d according to my needs